# Stackoverflow exception in parallel QuickSort with small variance of input

Tags: java, concurrency, quicksort, fork-join

I have implemented the Quick Sort algorithm using Java `ForkJoin` library for concurrency. I am testing the solution with a large number of randomly generated `Integers`.

This all works fine when the variance for the randomly generated `Integers` is large, ie. `random.nextInt()`. But whenever the variance is reduced, ie. `random.nextInt() % 10`, I am getting the exception trace like this:

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.setExceptionalCompletion(ForkJoinTask.java:489) ...
```

**Test.java**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final int SIZE = 160_000;
    Random rand = new Random();
    Integer[] data = new Integer[SIZE];

    for(int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        data[i] = rand.nextInt() % 10; // works for "rand.nextInt()", breaks with "% 10"
    }

    long t0 = System.currentTimeMillis();
    QSort.sort(data);
    long t1 = System.currentTimeMillis();

    System.out.println("Sorted: " + QSort.isSorted(data));
    System.out.println("Time elapsed: " + (t1-t0) + " ms");
}
```

**QSort.java**

```
public class QSort {

    private static class QSortJob<T extends Comparable<T>> extends RecursiveAction {

        private final T[] arr;

        private final int left;

        private final int right;

        private QSortJob(T[] arr, int left, int right) {
            this.arr = Objects.requireNonNull(arr);
            this.left = left;
            this.right = right;
        }

        @Override
        protected void compute() {
            if (left < right) {
                int pivotIndex = left + (right - left) / 2;

                pivotIndex = partition(pivotIndex);

                invokeAll(new QSortJob<>(arr, left, pivotIndex-1),
                        new QSortJob<>(arr, pivotIndex+1, right));
            }
        }


        private int partition(int pivotIndex) {
            T pivotValue = arr[pivotIndex];

            swap(pivotIndex, right);

            int storeIndex = left;
            for (int i=left; i<right; i++) {
                if (arr[i].compareTo(pivotValue) < 0) {
                    swap(i, storeIndex);
                    storeIndex++;
                }
            }

            swap(storeIndex, right);

            return storeIndex;
        }

        private void swap(int i, int j) {
            T tmp = arr[i];
            arr[i] = arr[j];
            arr[j] = tmp;
        }       
    }

    public static <T extends Comparable<T>> void sort(T[] arr) {
        ForkJoinPool pool = new ForkJoinPool();
        pool.invoke(new QSortJob<>(arr, 0, arr.length-1));
        pool.shutdown();
    }
```

Why does this happen on a small input variance, and what's the way to fix it?

Comment: What release of Java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has to do with how the quick sort algorithm partitions the (sub-)arrays when too many values become duplicated. Long story made short, you are becoming closer to the worst runtime behavior of the quicksort, which leads to a stack depth proportional to the size of the  array to be sorted as opposed to the logarithm of this size.

**Analysis**
To illustrate this, let's have a look at an example.

Let's simplify the example by choosing the remainder of the random generated values when divided by 2. This allows us to focus on only two distinct values.

We will print the following information while the quick sort executes to help us investigate: `depth`, which is how deep in the stack we are in the recursion (for simplicity's sake, we will ignore the additional calls made by the fork-join framework, this does not affect the analysis), `branch`, which is whether we are operating on the left or right side of a partitioned sub-array, and the `length` of this sub-array:

```
private static class QSortJob<T extends Comparable<T>> extends RecursiveAction {
    private final T[] arr;
    private final int left;
    private final int right;
    private final int depth;
    private final String branch;

    private QSortJob(T[] arr, int left, int right, int depth, String branch) {
        this.arr = Objects.requireNonNull(arr);
        this.left = left;
        this.right = right;
        this.depth = depth;
        this.branch = branch;
    }

    @Override
    protected void compute() {
        if (left < right) {
            int pivotIndex = left + (right - left) / 2;
            System.out.println(String.format("Branch=%s, depth=%d, length(subarray)=%d", branch, depth, right - left + 1));

            pivotIndex = partition(pivotIndex);
            invokeAll(new QSortJob<>(arr, left, pivotIndex-1, depth + 1, "Left"),
                    new QSortJob<>(arr, pivotIndex+1, right, depth + 1, "Right"));
        }
    }
```

The first call will look like:

```
pool.invoke(new QSortJob<>(arr, 0, arr.length-1, 0, "Root"));
```

Let's generate the distribution of values with:

```
for(int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    data[i] = Math.abs(rand.nextInt()) % 2;
}
```

I ran the program with a size of 100,000 - it was enough to me to reproduce the stack overflow. Let's have a look at the logs of the first calls:

```
Branch=Root, depth=0, length(subarray)=100000
Branch=Right, depth=1, length(subarray)=99999
Branch=Right, depth=2, length(subarray)=99998
Branch=Right, depth=3, length(subarray)=99997
Branch=Left, depth=4, length(subarray)=49882
Branch=Right, depth=4, length(subarray)=50114
Branch=Right, depth=5, length(subarray)=49881
Branch=Right, depth=5, length(subarray)=50113
Branch=Right, depth=6, length(subarray)=49880
Branch=Right, depth=6, length(subarray)=50112
Branch=Right, depth=7, length(subarray)=49879
Branch=Right, depth=7, length(subarray)=50111
Branch=Right, depth=8, length(subarray)=49878
```

1. What did happen as we enter the second call to `QSortJob#compute`? We have a sub-array which is the length of the original array minus one. We can conclude from this, based on our understanding of your algorithm, that the partitioning method found the value `0` for pivot, because all values in our array are `>= 0`, and therefore none of them is "moved" to the left of the pivot, and as a consequence the pivot stays at its initial position, i.e. index 0, and the size of the right array becomes the initial size minus one.
2. The algorithm then calls itself on the left branch, which has only one element, and returns immediately, and no log is printed for it.
3. The same reasoning as (1) applies to the forth and fifth calls (lines 3 and 4).
4. The fifth line is generated after `1` was selected as a pivot. Under the assumption of "reasonably" uniformly distributed occurrences of `0` and `1`, we have roughly as many `0` as `1`, which explains the sizes of `49882` and `99997 - 49882 = 50115` for the left and right subarrays, filled with a unique value, `0` or `1` respectively.
5. This is where the key to understand the stack overflow is. We can reproduce the reasoning applied in (1) on the current left and right sub-arrays which, because they are made of a unique value, will render the partitioning inefficient, because the pivot value will always stay at the leftmost index of the subarray to be sorted. We can observe this pattern in our logs as we go deeper in the stack, as the size of the "right" sub-array always decreases by 1: 50114, 50113, 50112, 50111... and 49881, 49880, 49879, 49878... Worth noting that we never print a log for the left branch because it will only be made of one element - as it was in (2).
6. We can conclude by induction that from this point on, we will have to make roughly `100,000 / 2 = 50,000` recursive calls, thereby over-filling the stack.

This analysis can be translated to the case where we take the remainder of the random generated values when divided by 10. This leaves us with the set of values `{-9, -8, -7, -6, -5, -4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}` With a size of `160,000` for the input arrays, and under the uniformly distributed assumption, this leaves us with `160000 / 19 ~= 8421` occurrences of each of these values in the array. Let's reproduce the reasoning we adopted earlier: at some point during the recursion, we will have segregated each of these values in arrays of size ~8421, and from there, the algorithm will call itself 8421 times, overflowing the stack again.

**Conclusion**
As we just saw, the quick sort algorithm, due to its partitioning scheme, is sensible to the content of array to be sorted. It is therefore "vulnerable" whereby it cannot provide a guaranteed, consistent runtime complexity for every input.

A canonical example to illustrate this is an array already sorted, or, as we could have chosen, an array filled with a unique value:

```
Arrays.fill(data, 0);
```

**Further analysis and comments**
This is of course not a fatality: your algorithm can be adapted to detect these "edge" cases to switch to another strategy and avoid deep, inefficient recursive calls.I can describe further what I mean by this if you so wish.

Comment: Great answer, thanks! Yes, please do tell what would be the strategy to avoid such scenarios. I'm guessing some kind of fallback to non-recursive computation of the sub-array when the size of the sub-array is less than some treshold?

Comment: Yes sure - I will try to follow-up tonight (UTC)

Comment: Yes - sorry for the delay! I didn't forget, I will test some code at home :-)

Answer (score 0):

When we use `% 10` , lot of duplicate values will be generated and that is causing the problem.

Further calls are stopped when all the values in the sub array are equal and there by reducing the unnecessary calls, jun ran without any issues for 3000000 elements

```
      @Override
    protected void compute() {
        if (left < right) {
            int pivotIndex = left + (right - left) / 2;

            int[] pivotArr = partition(pivotIndex);
            pivotIndex=pivotArr[0];
            int pivotFlag=0;
            pivotFlag=pivotArr[1];
            if(pivotFlag!=1)
            invokeAll(new QSortJob<>(arr, left, pivotIndex-1),
                    new QSortJob<>(arr, pivotIndex+1, right));
        }
    }


    private int[] partition(int pivotIndex) {
        T pivotValue = arr[pivotIndex];
        int uniqVal=0,uniqFlag=0;
        int pivotArr[];
        swap(pivotIndex, right);

        int storeIndex = left;
        for (int i=left; i<right; i++) {
            if(pivotValue==arr[i]) ++uniqVal;
            if (arr[i].compareTo(pivotValue) < 0) {
                swap(i, storeIndex);
                storeIndex++;
            }
        }

        swap(storeIndex, right);
        if(uniqVal == (right-left)) {
            uniqFlag=1;
            System.out.println("Yes, it is equal--"+uniqVal);
            }
        pivotArr=new int[]{storeIndex,uniqFlag};
        return pivotArr;
    }
```

Comment: No, that changed nothing.

Comment: @wesleyy can you check if adding the condition to stop running when the elements are equal is working, it worked for me